# Express.js Route with Param is Yielding 404 when Queried from the Client

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, parameters, routes

I defined a server route as such: (https://github.com/leptone/lang-exchange-react/blob/master/server.js)

```
app.route('user/:username')
.get((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.username)
    db.findOne({ 
        username: req.params.username 
    }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err
        else if(!user) res.send(true)
        else res.send(false)
    })
})
```

I am making a request to the route from the client like this:(https://github.com/leptone/lang-exchange-react/blob/master/src/components/SignUp.js#L35)

```
fetch(`/user/${username}`)
        .then(resp => resp.text())
        .then(answer => console.log(answer))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Each time I make this request I get an error message in the client console:

```
GET <DNS>:<PORT>/user/test 404 (Not Found)
```

And the promise returned by resp.text() resolves to (ie the server's response to the HTTP request):

```
Cannot GET /user/test
```

For whatever reason the server is behaving as if the '/user/:username' route isn't defined.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you forgot a `/` in your route :P 
`app.route('/user/:username')`